# Google Checkout for peer-to-peer payments

Tags: google-checkout

I'm trying to figure out if I can use Google Checkout for peer-to-peer payments. It seems fairly straightforward to set it up between a vendor and customers, but I'm not sure if it works well (or at all) for p2p.

Can I use Google Checkout to do peer to peer payments?

Comment: oops, forgot to explicitly add one. Sorry.

Comment: What do you mean by "peer to peer payments"? Google Checkout is not an account as such (unlike Paypal) so stroes no money in it, meaning all transactions are between a supplier and customer (by they individuals or companies)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the answer is **no**.

See this [article](https://checkout.google.com/support/sell/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=134420).

**"Google Checkout cannot be used as a person to person money transfer service at this time."**